# Тормозит viewpager при перелистывании фрагментов

Tags: java, android

Я новичок в этом деле,сильно не пинайте!
Всего у меня 2 фрагмента.
Код полностью рабочий,нареканий нет.Только при пролистывании фрагментов тормозят сами фрагменты,проект чистил,студию перезапускал.
Код фрагмента в котором отображаю свои фрагменты и реализую основную логику.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
    static final String TAG = PageFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    ImageView[] arr_imageA = new ImageView[3];
    ImageView[] arr_imageB = new ImageView[7];
    ImageView fab;
    Animation anim;
    boolean isClicked;
    Toast toast;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int pageNumber;
    NotificationManager manager;
    Notification myNotication;

    private int[] soundsRawResIds = new int[] {R.raw.belarus, R.raw.russian, R.raw.ukraina,
            R.raw.litva, R.raw.england, R.raw.japan, R.raw.france};
    private int[] buttonIds = new int[] {R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4, R.id.b5 ,R.id.b6, R.id.b7};
    private int[] fragments = new int[]{R.id.imageView1,R.id.imageView2,R.id.imageView3};

    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
        fab();
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);


    }


        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            arr_imageA[i] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(fragments[i]);

            arr_imageA[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    v.startAnimation(anim);
                   // mediaPlayer.start();
                    playSample(R.raw.click_sound);
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.imageView1:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a1.class);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView2://todo копипаст
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a2.class);
                            break;
                        case R.id.imageView3:
                            startActivity(getActivity(), a3.class);
                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

            if (pageNumber == 1) {
                View rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
                for (int index = 0; index < buttonIds.length; index++) {
                    arr_imageB[index] = (ImageView) rootViewB.findViewById(buttonIds[index]);
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {
                    arr_imageB[j].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            v.startAnimation(anim);
                                switch (v.getId()) {
                                case R.id.b1:
                                {

                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);
                                         }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b2:

                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);

                                        }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b3:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);

                                        }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b4:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
                                         }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b5: {
                                    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
                                }
                                    break;
                                case R.id.b6: {
                                    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                    playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);

                                }

                                    break;
                                case R.id.b7:
                                {
                                            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
                                            playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);

                                        }
                                break;
                            }

                            return false;  }

                    });
                }

                return rootViewB;

            }


        }

        return rootView;
    }
    public void startActivity(final Context activityContext, final Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(activityContext, activityClass));
            }
        }, 200);
    }
    private void fab(){
        fab = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
        final Animation anim_fab = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab_animation);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fab.startAnimation(anim_fab);
                //если isClicked возращает true
                fab.setImageResource(isClicked ? R.drawable.speaker_icon_on_shadow :
                        R.drawable.speaker_icon_off_shadow);
                float volume = isClicked ? 1.0f : 0f;
                setVolume(volume, volume);
                toast.makeText(getActivity(), isClicked ? R.string.sound_on : R.string.sound_off,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isClicked = !isClicked;
            }
        });
    }




    private void playSample(int resid) {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getContext().getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            afd.close();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to play audio queue do to exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void stopPlayerIfNeeded() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }


    public void setVolume(float left, float right) {
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(left, right);
    }

   @Override
    public void onPause(){
      if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
           // mediaPlayer.stop();
           // mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
          Notify();
        }
       super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){


        super.onResume();
    }


    public void Notify() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        builder.setTicker("Потешки-колыбельные");
        builder.setContentTitle("Колыбельные");
        builder.setContentText("Нажмите чтобы вернуться в приложение");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setNumber(100);
        builder.build();
        myNotication = builder.getNotification();
        manager  = (NotificationManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(100, builder.build());

    }
```

}

Класс адаптер:

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    static final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);



    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

Класс маин:

```
public class MainActivity  extends FragmentActivity {

    SharedPreferences prefs = null;
    Intent intent;
    ViewPager pager;

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        intent = new Intent(this, First_activity.class);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.example.navigate.viewpager1", MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
         startActivity(intent);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        }
    }
```

}

И сами фрагменты:

```
public class fragment extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment);

    }
}

public class fragment2 extends FragmentActivity {
    LinearLayout linLayout;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment2);

    }



}
```

Логи:

```
05-07 01:41:44.864 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy, referenced from method com.example.navigate.viewpager1.PageFragment.access$super
05-07 01:41:44.864 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4144: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performDestroy ()V
05-07 01:41:44.864 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x04d4
05-07 01:41:44.864 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performLowMemory ()V from Lcom/example/navigate/viewpager1/PageFragment;)
05-07 01:41:44.864 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performLowMemory, referenced from method com.example.navigate.viewpager1.PageFragment.access$super
05-07 01:41:44.864 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4146: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performLowMemory ()V
05-07 01:41:44.864 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x04da
05-07 01:41:44.868 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performOptionsMenuClosed (Landroid/view/Menu;)V from Lcom/example/navigate/viewpager1/PageFragment;)
05-07 01:41:44.868 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsMenuClosed, referenced from method com.example.navigate.viewpager1.PageFragment.access$super
05-07 01:41:44.868 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4148: Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;.performOptionsMenuClosed (Landroid/view/Menu;)V
05-07 01:41:44.868 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x052f
05-07 01:41:44.872 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 94K, 4% free 4299K/4476K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-07 01:41:44.884 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 19.876MB for 16384012-byte allocation
05-07 01:41:44.888 4536-4545/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 20298K/20480K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
05-07 01:41:45.044 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 1% free 23845K/24028K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
05-07 01:41:45.076 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 27455K/27640K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
05-07 01:41:45.108 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 1% free 31059K/31236K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
05-07 01:41:45.116 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 46.010MB for 16384012-byte allocation
05-07 01:41:45.284 4536-4542/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 1% free 47057K/47240K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
05-07 01:41:45.396 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/FragmentManager: moveToState: Fragment state for PageFragment{527c7008 #1 id=0x7f0d0071 android:switcher:2131558513:1} not updated inline; expected state 3 found 2
05-07 01:41:45.400 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so

                                                                       [ 05-07 01:41:45.400  4536: 4536 D/         ]
                                                                       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7bbc4a0, tid 4536
05-07 01:41:45.408 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
05-07 01:41:45.408 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
05-07 01:41:45.436 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-07 01:41:45.440 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
05-07 01:41:45.440 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
05-07 01:41:45.448 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
05-07 01:41:45.448 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
05-07 01:41:45.448 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
05-07 01:41:45.452 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-07 01:42:11.860 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-07 01:42:17.236 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-07 01:42:19.224 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
05-07 01:42:23.236 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-07 01:42:27.748 4536-4536/com.example.navigate.viewpager1 W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: Слишком многа букафф - ниасилил. И почему вы упорно активити называете фрагментами и именуете их с маленькой буквы?...

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
понял,буду сам себя доставать из ямы))

Comment: Тоже не осилил много текста. Заметил, что у вас там есть массивы ImageView. Отображение картинок для андроида очень ресурсозатратный процесс. Обратите внимание на это, может что-нибудь найдете.

Comment: всем спасибо,действительно, проблема закл. в картинках, сжал картинки и лаги пропали