# Можно ли программно задать фон у виджета android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android

Делаю в `onCreate`:

```
viewPager =(ViewPager)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_content);
```

это в `onCreateView`:

```
viewPager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.potehki_fon);
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/speaker_icon_on_shadow"

        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

При выполнении кода вижу такую ошибку:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                                                                               at com.example.potehki.potehki.PageFragment.onCreate(PageFragment.java:63)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор вам говорит, что вы перепутали один вью с другим. А именно вы пытаетесь ViewPager найти по ИД  main_content, тогда как с этим ИД у вас CoordinatorLayout.

Читайте сообщения компилятора и будьте внимательны.

Comment: сорри,плохо копировал)
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
 coordinatorLayout =(CoordinatorLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_content);
 coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.potehki_fon);
т.е так можно делать или это гавн.код?

Comment: @upward, если вы хотите менять фон при листании фрагментов, то так оно менять фон должно, но совсем не так, как вы можете ожидать. В этом случае лучше повесить слушатель листания страниц на сам пэйджер и в нём менять фон в зависимости от позиции выбранного фрагмента.

Comment: я так и делал,вот в этой теме:
[ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521076/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82-viewpager-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?noredirect=1#comment642669_521076)
только у меня тормозит пролистование,удаляю фон и ничего не лагает,вот я и ищу выход

Comment: @upward, ну, значит проблема в слишком большом размере файла фона, а нне в способе его назначения. Уменьшите размер файла фона.

Comment: что-то ен могу понять,дела. так:
coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fon1);
это в View onCreateView
потом проверяю:
if (pageNumber == 1)
то делаю так:
 coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fon2);
а на деле так:
запускается приложение,но фон не меняется,т.е при пролистовании я вижу fon1 у фрагмента 2, а должен быть fon2

Comment: @upward, я не понял что вы хотите сказать. Если вы хотите менять фон при пролистывании, то надо его менять не во фрагментах, а в onPageChangeListener`-e `ViewPager`-a

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
а примером можете поделиться?
что-то не нашел про фон ничего

Comment: @upward, вам надо не про фон искать - фон у вас в коде нормально меняется. Вам надо искать слушатель переключения страниц пейджера. Это - onPageChangeListener, Назначается методом `addOnPageChangeListener()`